# Angular 2 Change detection from an Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my app I have a component that has a method that is called from an input in another component, this method updates the model that should be reflected in a ngFor that iterates over the model, however no changes are observed.

Here is a snippet from my app.component.html:

```
<app-schedule #scheduleReference [candidates]="candidatesReference"></app-schedule>
<app-candidates #candidatesReference></app-candidates>
```

In schedule.component.ts:

```
@Input() candidates: CandidatesComponent;

addCandidate() { this.candidates.addCandidate( ... ) }
```

In candidates.component.ts:

```
addCandidate(candidate: Candidate) {
  this.candidateService.addCandidate(candidate);
  var candidates = this.candidateService.getCandidates();
}
```

And finally the view that is *not* updating - candidates.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let candidate of candidates" class="draggable candidate" data-id="{{candidate.id}}">{{candidate.name}}</div>
```

When I initialize the component the list generates as expected but it is not updated when called from schedule component. How does the change detection not pick up that the model has changed?

Comment: What do you expect to happen. `candidates` seems to be a component. What should `let candidate of candidates` do?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry for the confusion. `candidates` is a component reference in the `schedule` component. However in the `candidates` component, it is a private variable which contains the list of Candidate objects. 'export class CandidatesComponent implements OnInit {

  candidates: Candidate[]; ...'

Comment: I'm still confused. Your problem might be related with Angulars change detection, where changes to object properties are not detected (except they are bound to in the view) - only if the object instance is different a change is detected (same for arrays - while `*ngFor` itself checks arrays for changes).

Comment: If I call candidates.component.ts `addCandidate(candidate)` within the candidates component (ie. ngOnInit), it is reflected in the view, adding to the list displayed. However when I call the same method from another component, the schedule component with an imported CandidateComponent reference, the list in the view is not updated. Hope that clears things up a little!

Comment: Sorry, no idea, maybe someone else.

Comment: In `addCandidate()` in candidates.component.ts, `var candidates = ...` is local to the function, so the view won't be able to see whatever you put into that `candidates` variable.   If using `this.candidates = ...` doesn't fix your problem, create a plunker to replicate the issue.